# uninitialized constant when using nested_forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, undefined, nested-forms

I am using the nested_forms gem and want to have a relation such as described here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?autoplay=true

I have a class User which has Projects and those have ProjectFiles:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :user_id, presence: true

    has_many :project_files, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_files, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:filepath].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class ProjectFile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    validates :project_id, presence: true

    mount_uploader :filepath, ProjectFileUploader
end
```

In my partial where I keep the fields for the projects I just call f.fields_for :project_files

```
<%= f.fields_for :project_files do |pf_form| %>
```

I saw lots of questions like mine and the problem was always a mix up with the plural forms and/or wrong class names. However, I cannot find any error in my relations but I always receive:

```
uninitialized constant Project::ProjectFile
```

Comment: I have also tried the following in the console:
"ProjectFile".underscore --> project_file
"ProjectFile".tableize --> project_files

Comment: Please post your controller action code along with full trace that throws this error.  I suspect you've missed something similar to `@project.project_files.build` in your action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I gave up and I deleted my model project_file.
I generated a new one called projectfile

```
class Projectfile < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :project
validates :project_id, presence: true

mount_uploader :filepath, ProjectFileUploader
end


class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
validates :user_id, presence: true

has_many :projectfiles, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :projectfiles, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:filepath].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

It's working now... I have no idea what was wrong with the first model...